# SharePoint online O365 hide site contents from gear menu

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, nintex-workflow

I am using SharePoint O365 with Nintex Forms for business forms automation. I would like to hide/restrict the Site Contents to the visitors with Read permission.

I tried with assiging Restricted read, also by editing the Read permission level by unchecking the **View Application Pages** Permission. With this, the Site Contents are hidden, but the Nintex forms are not loaded. Is there any way I can hide it or restrict it if someone manually enter the Site contents url and browses?

Answer (score 0):

By default, users with read permissions could access the site contents page.

As far as I know, there is no other ways to hide/restrict the site contents page. Unchecking the View Application Pages Permission is the only way.

Comment: Unchecking View Application Pages doesn't help as i will not be able to view the nintex forms by doing so.